# PDOStatement::nextRowset() not working with dblib and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, odbc

### The Problem

I have recently moved my web application from a Windows Server to a Linux Server, and in doing this, I have had to make a lot of changes... One of which is the way I communicate with my MSSQL server.

I was using the Windows PDO_SQLSRV driver to speak to the databases, but am now using the dblib driver with Freetds etc. Everything works as it should apart from multiple recordsets and `PDOStatement::nextRowset()`. When I try to execute this function, I get:

> PDOStatement::nextRowset(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support multiple rowsets in /somefile/

### What I have tried

I have searched Google for this error and whilst I was able to find potential solutions (dating back to 2006), it seems none of these solutions are available.

I looked at [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50755) but wasnt able to implement the solution as it didn't say where it was.

### My Question

If not already clear, I need a way of returning multiple recordsets from an MSSQL databases via PHP on Linux, without getting the error that I am currently receiving... Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-general/073wpk99cf/pdo-mssql-multiple-rowsets)

It seems to be on the Developer Todo list:

> It Is doable. The native mssql/dblib extension does support that
>   features. I just have'nt had the time to code it for pdo_dblib.
>
> Frank

If you consider writing parts of your scripts in native lib, [check here][2]

---

**EDIT:**

It turns out the `thread` I linked to was old and the bug has been fixed since then.

The solution was to upgrade the PHP to a newer version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am looking into what you have posted now. What I don't understand is why this bug was reported back in 2007 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57593), but it still hasn't been fixed! The post above claims it has but it hasnt... Unless I need to upgrade my PHP version? I am using 5.3.3 as this is was came on CentOS so I assume it is the stable version for CentOS...

Comment: @BenCarey Yes indeed version `5.3.3` is quite old now, it is best to use most recent stable release

Comment: Thanks @meda. +1 for your help anyway, it is now sorted by updating PHP. Feel free to update your answer and I will accept that instead :-)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this issue was fixed in one of the later PHP versions. I do not know which version precisely, but I am now using PHP version 5.5.18 and `nextRowset()` is working as it should be.